# timeout when testing promise rejection with sinon and chai-as-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon

I have a function which wraps a third party `child-process-promise`, which itself wraps `spawn` in promise.

```
let spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;


run(cmd, args = []) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let command = spawn(cmd, args);
      let childProcess = command.childProcess;
      let result = '';

      childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        result += data.toString();
      });

      try {
        const res = await command;
        resolve(result);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          reject(`Command "${cmd}" not found`);
        } else {
          reject('Exec err' + err);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Testing the resolve was quite straightforward and I manage to get my stdout data passed to result then detected by `chai-as-promised` using `await expect(shellRun).to.eventually.become('hello world');`

Our problem is when we try to test the catch part of our method.

```
const ERROR = 'someError';

beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

    spawnEvent = new events.EventEmitter();
    spawnEvent.stdout = new events.EventEmitter();

    spawnStub = sandbox.stub();
    spawnStub.returns({ childProcess: spawnEvent });

    spawnStub.withArgs(ERRORED, ARGUMENTS).throws(ERROR));

    shell = proxyquireStrict('../../lib/utils/spawnWrapper', {
      'child-process-promise': {
        spawn: spawnStub
      }
    }
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  describe('when a generic error occurs', () => {
    it('should reject the promise', async () => {
      const shellRun = run(ERRORED, ARGUMENTS);

      await expect(shellRun).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Exec err' + ERROR);
    });
  });
```

We manage to get `childProcessPromiseSpawn` to throw an error conditionally by playing with ou `spawnStub.withArgs`. But a timeout is encountered:

```
(node:15425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: someError
(node:15425) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 838)

1 failing

  1) run method
       when a generic error occurs
         should reject the promise:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

We tried `spawnStub.withArgs(ERRORED, ARGUMENTS).rejects` instead of `throws` without more success. Changing `someError` for `new Error('someError')` doesn't work either.

We also tried to catch at test level

```
try {
  await run(ERRORED, ARGUMENTS);
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).to.equal('Exec err' + ERROR);
}
```

But the timeout still occurs.

Comment: Did you try `const shellRun = await run(ERRORED..); expect(shellRun)...`?

Comment: Yes we did it triggers the timeout. Please note await expect() works for resolve testing.

Comment: Try to return the promise :`it('should reject the promise', () => {
      const shellRun = run(ERRORED, ARGUMENTS);

      expect(shellRun).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Exec err' + ERROR);
      return shellRun;
    });`

Comment: Still the same result: `(node:4045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: someError`, `(node:4045) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: Are you sure than the default test timeout is sufficient for your test? It seems that the test fails due to timeout then the promise is not ended and the error `Unhandled promise` is thrown

Comment: since the error is instantaneously emitted, I don't see the timeout of 2000ms sufficient. I just tested, to be sure, to set it to 1 minute and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hey @BlackHoleGalaxy, Did you got any luck here?

Answer (score 0):

This depend of which testing library you are using. Each library has a dedicated timeout.

For **mocha** you can define it in the test suite or for a unique test

https://mochajs.org/#timeouts

Comment: The timeout is not the problem. The timeout just indicates the error I trigger is not catched by test framework. Running test on mocha with chai and sinon.